# Doubt in a certain equation of a research paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In the given paper, I am stuck at equation (7). The equation that I am trying to solve for particle outside the well is : (1/g)*(g'') + (1/(r*g))*g' - (k_o)^2 = 0 where g = Radial wave function. r = Distance from origin.

The solution I arrived at is : A*J_0(i*k_o*r) + B*Y_0(i*k_o*r) where J ,Y are Bessel functions of first kind of order zero & second kind of order zero respectively.

My queries are : 1.) How can I reduce the solution in the form of equation (7) , i.e. , Psi = A*e^(-k_o*r) / (r^0.5) ?

2.) Am I solving the correct differential equation?

Link to research paper: [abstract](http://www.ias.ac.in/pramana/v73/p573/abs.htm) [pdf](http://www.ias.ac.in/pramana/v73/p573/fulltext.pdf)

Relevant equations from this paper:

[image]

Comment: There are two equations (7): the actual wave function (an evanescent wave, the solution to your equation 4), and the expression for the wave number (which is a direct function of the energy deficit outside the well). Which of these do you have trouble with?

Comment: Related to Floris' comment: Please include all the necessary materials in your question: It should be self-contained

Comment: Toward Danu's comment. We have the MathJax rendering engine active on the site which means that [you can display very nice equations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) by writing them in a LaTeX-alike language and putting them between `$`s.

Comment: Hi @Floris , I am having trouble in arriving at the Psi (the wave function). I solved the differential equation but I am arriving at Bessel functions , but the solution is of the form of exponential function. I do not know where am I wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The general form, equivalent to eqn (5) but for outside the well, is

$\Psi_o = A_o \dfrac{e^{-k_o r}}{\sqrt{r}} + B_o \dfrac{e^{k_o r}}{\sqrt{r}}$

But just like we know $\Psi_i$ is not infinite at the origin, we also know that $\Psi_o$ doesn't go to infinity at large values of *r*. So we know $B_o$ must be 0.

Comment: Can you please tell which differential equation did you solve to arrive at this solution ?

Comment: I think it's the same equation but with negative net energy, and therefore an imaginary wavenumber- leading to either the solution blowing up at infinity (not physical) or an evanescence wave (which is the solution).