# Problem in Solving an Equation in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I am trying to reproduce this paper : http://www.ias.ac.in/pramana/v73/p573/fulltext.pdf

But, somehow I am stuck at equation (7). The equation that I am trying to solve for particle outside the well is : (1/g)*(g'') + (1/(r*g))*g' - (k_o)^2 = 0 
where g = Radial wave function. r = Distance from origin.

The solution I arrived at is : A*J_0(i*k_o*r) + B*Y_0(i*k_o*r) where J ,Y are Bessel functions of first kind of order zero & second kind of order zero respectively.

My queries are :
1.) How can I reduce the solution in the form of equation (7) , i.e. , Psi = A*e^(-k_o*r) / (r^0.5) ?

2.) Am I solving the correct differential equation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doubt in a certain equation of a research paper](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131691/)

Comment: Hi Anchit Virmani. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.